# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Exception

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to read a log file and trying to print all the logs between a certain dates but i end up getting this exception when am trying to retrieve date from the log.
this is my code and it is actually printing some log messages

```
public class Teat {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\log.log"));
        String sCurrentLine;
        try {
            String startDate = "12 Dec 2013";
            String endDate = "12 Dec 2013";

            Date dateStart = formatter.parse(startDate);
            Date dateEnd = formatter.parse(endDate);
            Date logDate = null;
            int sDay = dateStart.getDate();
            int sMonth = dateStart.getMonth();
            int sYear = dateStart.getYear();
            int eDay = dateEnd.getDate();
            int eMonth = dateEnd.getMonth();
            int eYear = dateEnd.getYear();
            String date;
            int i=0;
              ArrayList<String> Sub_string = new ArrayList<String>();
            do {
                sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
                Sub_string.add(sCurrentLine.substring(0, 11));

                logDate = formatter.parse(Sub_string.get(i));
                int lDay = logDate.getDate();
                int lMonth = logDate.getMonth();
                int lYear = logDate.getYear();
                if (lYear >= sYear && lYear <= eYear) 
                {
                    if (lMonth >= sMonth && lMonth <= eMonth)

                    {
                        if (lDay >= sDay && lDay <= eDay) {
                            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{System.out.println("pls ented valid dates");}
                i++;
            }while(sCurrentLine!=null);
        }

        catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

}
```

error is

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index 
out of range: 11
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at Teat.main(Teat.java:41)
```

Comment: `Sub_string.add(sCurrentLine.substring(0, 11));` what is the value of `sCurrentLine` here ?

Comment: the line that  i read from the log file,

Comment: yes what is the value of that line ?

Comment: the value is 12 Dec 2013

Comment: why don't you use regex for that?

Comment: `\\d{2}\\s\\w{3}\\s\\d{4}\\s` try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `whlie((sCurrentLine = br.readLine())!=null)` instead of `do while` otherwise you will end with `NullPointerException`.

and check `if(sCurrentLinet.isEmpty()&&sCurrentLinet.length()>=11)` before processing.

Answer (score 2):

> yes what is the value of that line ? –  Jigar Joshi 3 mins ago   edit
>   the value is 12 Dec 2013 –  user3117965 19 secs ago

`12 Dec 2013` is 11 character long `String` so the last character is at the position 10 (first character is at 0 index), accessing 11th element will give put you out of bound and so the Exception

Comment: the size of the string is some 100+ but still i am getting the same problem

Comment: it could be good for some cases, but when it is the value you mentioned, it will fail with exception stopping the program to progress in this unhandled case

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub_string.add(sCurrentLine.substring(0, 11));
```

is giving problem. Add a check before calling the `substring(start, end)` function

```
if (sCurrentLine != null && end>= start && end <= sCurrentLine.length())
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check whether all the lines in the log are atleast 11 characters long? You will get StringOutOfBoundsException if any of the lines are less than 11 chars in your case.
Also please change your code according to the suggestion from @Prabhakaran.

Comment: It s actually a problem with the log file format thanks guys anyway